# Placing Pagination arrows to the sides of the table instead of page numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have to move my pagination left and right arrow option to both the sides of the bootstrap-table-next from the bottom. And I don't want the numbers, just the arrows. 
I am using React,React-Bootstrap-table-next for front end. I have simply render the pagination option in my table . I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything satisfying my query.
Here is part of my code for pagination.

```
    <BootstrapTable keyField="Date"  
                            data={this.state.posts} 
                            columns={columns} 
                            filter={ filterFactory() }
                            filterPosition="bottom"
                            pagination={ paginationFactory() }
            />
```

Is there any other option along with pagination to achieve this?

[Bootstarp table next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8CSl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize by passing options to paginationFactory(options1) and options like below

```
            const options1 = {
            paginationSize: 4,
            pageStartIndex: 0,
            firstPageText: 'First',
            prePageText: ' << ',
            nextPageText: ' >> ',
            lastPageText: 'Last',
            nextPageTitle: 'First page',
            prePageTitle: 'Pre page',
            firstPageTitle: 'Next page',
            lastPageTitle: 'Last page',
            showTotal: true,
            paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
            sizePerPageList: [{
                text: '5', value: 5
            }, {
                text: '10', value: 10
            }, {
                text: 'All', value: data.length
            }]  the text
            };
```

BootstrapTable like this,

```
            <BootstrapTable
            caption={<CaptionElement />}
            keyField='last updated'
            data={ data }
            columns={ columnsData }
            pagination={ paginationFactory(options1) } 
            />
```